# kafka consume an undefined number of topics

Tags: apache-kafka

The topics are dynamically created, and there could be thousands of them. I need a way to detect when messages are produced so I can consume them. Moreover, I need to consume each topic independently so that I can then bulk a large number of messages into a database, each topic corresponding to a different table. So let's say I start consuming a topic, I would consume 1000 messages, bulk them in a database in one operation, then commit the reading in kafka. If I have 10 topics, I could use 10 consumers in parallel. The problem is if I end up with a large number of topics, and that most of them are idle (empty), I need a way to be notified that some topics become suddenly active, so that I don't have to launch thousands of idle consumers that do nothing most of the time.

The only solution I thought so far is using a single *signal topic* in addition to the real topics, in which the producers would produce in addition to the real topic. But I was wondering if there was another solution. Like polling the meta-data in kafka, maybe. But for what I've seen, I would have to iterate through all the topics matching a regex, then check the offsets of the partitions for each. I don't think it's possible to do that efficiently, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could track JMX metrics from the broker for incoming bytes per topic using Prometheus JMX Exporter, for example, then combine that with AlertManager to send some event/webhook upon some threshold of data to a consuming REST service, which would then start some consumers (maybe Kafka Connect tasks for a database?).

Or, like you said, use a signal topic since producer requests can be made to multiple topics at once.

> If I have 10 topics, I could use 10 consumers in parallel

You can have more parallel consumers if any of those topics have multiple partitions

> could be thousands of them

There's are reasonable limits on the number of topics a Kafka cluster can support, by the way, but it's upwards of hundreds of thousands, as of latest releases. Something to keep in mind, though.

> launch thousands of idle consumers that do nothing most of the time.

You could also use solutions like AWS Lambda or Kubernetes KEDA to auto scale up/down based on topic data (lag)